# Merge two dataframes on multiple columns, only if not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, data-imputation

Given two Pandas dataframes, how can I use the second dataframe to fill in missing values, given multiple key columns?

```
Col1  Col2 Key1  Key2  Extra1                   Col1     Col2    Key1  Key2         Col1  Col2 Key1  Key2  Extra1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
["A", "B", 1.10, 1.11, "Alice"]                                                     ["A", "B", 1.10, 1.11, "Alice"]         # left df has more non-NaNs, so leave it
["C", "D", 2.10, 2.11, "Bob"]                   [np.nan, np.nan, 1.10, 1.11]        ["C", "D", 2.10, 2.11, "Bob"]           # unmatched row should still exist
[np.nan, np.nan, 3.10, 3.11, "Charlie"]     +   ["E", "F", 3.10, 3.11]          =   ["E", "F", 3.10, 3.11, "Charlie"]       # left df has NaN, so fill in values
["I", np.nan, 5.10, 5.11, "Destiny"]            ["G", "H", 4.10, 4.11]              ["I", np.nan, 5.10, 5.11, "Destiny"]    # no matching values in second df, so leave it
[np.nan, "J", 6.10, 6.11, "Evan"]                                                   [np.nan, "J", 6.10, 6.11, "Evan"]       # no matching values in second df, so leave it
```

My attempt:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ["A", "B", 1.10, 1.11, "Alice"],
    ["C", "D", 2.10, 2.11, "Bob"],
    [np.nan, np.nan, 3.10, 3.11, "Charlie"],
    ["I", np.nan, 5.10, 5.11, "Destiny"],
    [np.nan, "J", 6.10, 6.11, "Evan"],
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['common_1', 'common_2', 'common_3', 'common_4', 'extra_1'])

data = [
    [np.nan, np.nan, 1.10, 1.11],
    ["E", "F", 3.10, 3.11],
    ["G", "H", 4.10, 4.11],
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['common_1_other', 'common_2_other', 'common_3_other', 'common_4_other'])


df3 = pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2,
    how="left",
    left_on=["common_3", "common_4"],
    right_on=["common_3_other", "common_4_other"],
)

"""
Want df3 to be:
    ["A", "B", 1.10, 1.11, "Alice"]
    ["C", "D", 2.10, 2.11, "Bob"]
    ["E", "F", 3.10, 3.11, "Charlie"]
    ["I", np.nan, 5.10, 5.11, "Destiny"]
    [np.nan, "J", 6.10, 6.11, "Evan"]
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove all the "_other" from the column names of your df2, then you can do

```
df1.set_index(['common_3', 'common_4']).fillna(df2.set_index(['common_3', 'common_4'])).reset_index()
```

This should fill nan in any of the Col1 and Col2 if there is a match in both Key1 and Key2

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is:

```
for col in df1:
    try:
        df1[col].fillna(df2[col+"_other"], inplace=True)
        
    except:
        pass
```

df1 output:

```
    common_1 common_2 common_3 common_4 extra_1
0   A           B       1.1      1.11   Alice
1   C           D       2.1      2.11   Bob
2   G           H       3.1      3.11   Charlie
3   I          NaN      5.1      5.11   Destiny
4   NaN        J        6.1      6.11   Evan
```